# Android Studio Kotlin databinding: Unresolved reference on BR

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, data-binding

I have some code that is generating a "red squiggly" error in Android Studio:

```
@get:Bindable
var title: String = ""
    set(value) {
        field = value
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.title)
    }
```

It complains that "title" is an unresolved reference on `BR.title`. Building and running works fine though, and this is the only error I can see. I debug there and see that it's gotten the value for `BR.title` correctly.

Still, I can't figure out how to make it go away. I verified that the generated BR class has the "title" field, but Android Studio refuses to recognize this. I've looked up people having this issue and have tried the following: (unsuccessfully)

- Closing Android Studio, deleting the .gradle, .idea and build folders and restarting
- Build -> Clean Project, Rebuild Project
- File -> Invalidate Caches and restart
- Disabling and enabling the Kotlin plugin
- Closing and reopening the project

I have also checked and I have `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in build.gradle.

Anyone know what's going on? I assume it must be holding onto some cache files somewhere but I don't know where.

Comment: just try another one, comment this line -> notifyPropertyChanged(BR.title)
after that Build -> Clean Project, Rebuild Project and after try to uncomment that line

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan That did not work either.

Comment: same situation. my problem is that the BR.foo is located in another module, which is indeed not found (unresolved) in my current.package.BR, but the app compiles and runs just fine, the BR is probably being merged anyway at the end. i am simply looking for a way to ignore them so that i won't see red lines in everywhere. sure i could also do things like `another.package.BR.foo` or `import another.pacakge.BR as BR2` then `BR2.foo`, but it just don't seem right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What fixed the problem for me was adding the following import to my files:

```
import androidx.databinding.library.baseAdapters.BR
```

I'm not entirely certain why this works, but it got rid of all the analysis problems and the application still compiles and works fine, so I'm personally happy.

Comment: It doesn't work. Still compilation fails. Gradle version - 4.2.2